# How do I call a service from within my Assembly?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, .net-3.5, class-library

I have a C# library. From within it, I want to call a static method that exists within the same library but through Javascript. Can I use WebResource to call a C# method?

Comment: What do you mean that your C# library will call a method "through javascript"? Please show how that makes any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to create a "proxy" to call that method. From javascript you can call
- Page Method
- HttpHandler
- Web Service

So will be your proxy on charge of calling the method you want and returning the result to javascript (more likely using json format)

Please let me know if you need some examples about how to use any of these mecanisms